# data from getStaticProps not showing in page (but is in props) with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm having trouble with NextJS rendering out my text from my API call. Basically, I make an external HTTP request to get some mock data. The mock data comes back in the form of props on the component via the getStaticProps method. In my JSX, I loop through the props via {props.data...}. I'll show the code below for brevity's sake.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback, memo } from "react";
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";

type Props = {
  props: {
    data: {}[];
  };
};

const Form: React.NamedExoticComponent<
  | React.RefAttributes<React.Component<{}, any, any>>
  | { children?: React.ReactNode }
> = memo((props) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ username: "", password: "" });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleSetFormData = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    },
    [formData]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexFlow: "column nowrap",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          height: "100vh",
        }}
      >
        <input onChange={handleSetFormData} type="text" name="username" />
        <input onChange={handleSetFormData} type="text" name="password" />
        <button onSubmit={handleSubmit} type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      {props.data.map((data) => {
        return (
          <ul key={data.id}>
            <li style={{ color: "red", fontSize: "24px" }}>{data.completed}</li>
            <li>{data.title}</li>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
});

type GetStaticPropsTypeInterface = {
  props: {
    data: {}[];
  };
};

export const getStaticProps: (
  props: React.PropsWithChildren<GetStaticPropsTypeInterface>
) => Promise<{ props: { data: any } }> = (props) => {
  return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      return {
        props: { data: res },
      };
    });
};

export default Form;
```

and the resulting HTML looks like this...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine, so I guess that problem might be related to something else.

My feeling is that you probably placed your Form component into `components` or `src` directory. Next.js is looking only inside of a `pages` directory and renders these pages on the server side.

Here's a dummy example - what is happening if you use this `getStaticProps` function outside of `pages` directory
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-feather-odg7x?file=/pages/index.tsx

So the solution would be to fetch the data in `pages/somePage.tsx` and forward props like this `<Form data={props.data}...`

Comment: You were right. There were several things different in our apps. 1.) My structure was like this "src->pages->index.tsx", and all of my code was inside index.tsx. Now, I have it set up to where Form is under components and index.tsx is still under pages, but now it has the getStaticProps and the mapping logic for the props to the UI. I also added the _app.tsx file under pages as well. It looks like I need to take a step back and review the file structure for a bit :). Thanks for your help!!